# Custom Module not working in Magento 2

Tags: php-5.4, magento2

I am created custom module in magento 2, but it's not working. Could you please suggest me where i went wrong?

**my Code is:**

**app/etc/config.php**

```
'modules' => 
  array (
    'Magento_Hello' => 1,
         ),
```

**app/code/local/Magento/Hello/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magento_Hello" schema_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Hello"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Magento/Hello/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="hello" frontName="hello">
            <module name="Magento_Hello" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Magento/Hello/Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Hello\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Magento/Hello/Block/Hello.php**

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Hello\Block;
class Hello extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Magento/etc/frontend/layout/hello_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
       <title>Hello World</title>
   </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Hello\Block\Hello" name="hello" template="success.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/local/Magento/etc/frontend/templates/success.phtml**

```
<?php echo 'Hi I am Magento 2'; ?>
```

Where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @Marius, Yes, not working.

Comment: Do you get an error? the module is not picked up? something crashes? be more exact

Comment: @Marius, I am getting 404 Not Found Error.

Comment: @Marius, Is there any options to Enable Logs in Magento 2? (From Magento Developer Section Enable Logs = Yes) like this.

Comment: @Marius, Module is Picked up, how in the seance it is showing on `Configuration-> Advanced` Tab.

Comment: I see you have your module in 'app/code/local' but local isn't used anymore. Try moving it to 'app/code'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are the issues with your module.
First of all lose the `local` in the folder path. There are no more codepools in magento 2.
So your `module.xml` should be placed in `app/code/Magento/Hello/etc/module.xml`. Do the same for the rest of the files.
And by the way. Use an other vendor name. Leave `Magento` for the core team. It works if you use the same one, but it's not a best practice.
Second...lose the `<sequence>` tag from `module.xml`. The way you did it, you tell Magento that your module needs to be loaded before itself which can't be done.  The `<sequence>` tag is used to [force load order](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/architecture/modules/mod_depend.html#m2devgde-moddep-load-order) and helps Magento deal with circular dependencies that haven't been removed yet.

Third...the layout file should not be placed in `etc`. It should be in `app/code/Magento/Hello/view/frontend/layout/hello_index_index.xml`.

The same goes for the template file. It should be in `app/code/Magento/Hello/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml`

And as a tip. In the controller you should not use `$this->_view`. It is deprecated and it will be gone soon.  Instead make your controller look like this:

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Hello\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

And clear the contents of folder `var/generation`

Comment: Thanks you now working fine. Yes your correct, after I removing `<sequence>` it's working. `<sequence>` (from Magento 2) means `<depends>` (from Magento) tag?.

Comment: Yes...Kind of..

Comment: More information on sequence can be found here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/architecture/modules/mod_depend.html#m2devgde-moddep-load-order

Comment: Deleting the contents of folder var/generation is important else you will get Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to...