# Creating custom module in magento2 show fatal error

Tags: error, magento2, controllers, php-5.4, dependency-injection

I working on creating custom module in magento 2, but it's not working. Could you please suggest me where i went wrong?.

My module code:

app/etc/config.php:

```
'modules' => 
  array (
    'Ramesh_Sample' => 1,
         ),
```

app/code/Ramesh/Sample/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Ramesh_Sample" schema_version="2.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/Ramesh/Sample/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="sample" frontName="sample">
            <module name="Ramesh_Sample" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

app/code/Ramesh/Sample/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Ramesh\Sample\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
//use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    private $_resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

app/code/Ramesh/Sample/Block/Sample.php

```
namespace Magento\Sample\Block;
class Sample extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
}
```

app/code/Ramesh/Sample/views/frontend/layout/sample_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Sample\Ramesh\Block\Sample" name="sample"      template="sample.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/Ramesh/Sample/view/frontend/templates/sample.phtml

```
<?php echo 'Hi I am Magento 2'; ?>
```

But I got the following error:

> a:4:{i:0;s:380:"Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to Ramesh\Sample\Controller\Index\Index::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory, none given, called in var/generation/Ramesh/Sample/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in app/code/Ramesh/Sample/Controller/Index/Index.php on line 14";i:1;s:6109:"#0 app/code/Ramesh/Sample/Controller/Index/Index.php(14): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(4096, 'Argument 2 pass...', '/var/www/html/m...', 14, Array)

Comment: See below link How to create Custom Module in Magento 2?

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54609/custom-module-not-working-in-magento-2

Answer (score 29):

try to delete your module from the var/generation/vendor-name/your-module and try to refresh the page and check if it's working.

Comment: Why do I have to delete the complete var/generation folder? Is there a faster process? Do I have to run bin/magento setup:di:compile every time?

Comment: You don't need to delete the complete var/generation folder try to identify your correct folder of your module Example : Demo /Module inside the var/generation .The code bin/magento setup:di:compile works only if you set the dependencies or code generation patterns set in di.xml

Comment: This has happened to me while working with controllers and I fixed it the same way, but can somebody explain why this happens in the first place?

Comment: tried the same above code and deleted files as mentioned but still showing error - HTTP ERROR 500,

Answer (score 10):

You can use below mentioned command and then refresh the page.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: It worked for me

Comment: Great ;) Working for me

Answer (score 1):

Replace code given below in your constructor

```
$this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
return parent::__construct($context);
```