# Magento 2 Custom Module Frontend Error

Tags: magento2, module, custom, frontend-error

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0

I'm following http://www.mage-world.com/blog/how-to-create-a-simple-module-in-magento-2-0.html

I have followed steps when i run it gives below error.

> {folder
>   path}\magento2\app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\Index\Index.php

```
namespace Custom\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory
     */
    protected $resultForwardFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        $resultPageFactory = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        // Add page title
        $resultPageFactory->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Sample Module'));

        // Add breadcrumb
        /** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs */
        $breadcrumbs = $resultPageFactory->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');
        $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('home', [
            'label' => __('Home'),
            'title' => __('Home'),
            'link' => $this->_url->getUrl('')
                ]
        );
        $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('custom_module', [
            'label' => __('Test'),
            'title' => __('Test')
                ]
        );
        return $resultPageFactory;
    }
}
```

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Recoverable Error: Argument
>   2 passed to Custom\Module\Controller\Index\Index::__construct() must
>   be an instance of Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory,
>   none given, called in {folder
>   path}\magento2\var\generation\Custom\Module\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor.php
>   on line 14 and defined in {folder
>   path}\magento2\app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\Index\Index.php on
>   line 21

Comment: Error seems to be with your dependency injection. Can you post first fold of your controller code and what you are seeking in your constructor.

Comment: Code Added in Question

Comment: @MikeSmith follow this link use full for you..http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78826/creating-custom-module-in-magento2-show-fatal-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this Code to **vendor\Module\Controller\Index/Index.php**

```
    <?php
    namespace vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

    use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

    class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory
         */
        protected $resultPageFactory;

        /**
         * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        ) {
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute() {
            $resultPageFactory = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

            // Add page title
            $resultPageFactory->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Sample Module'));

            // Add breadcrumb
            /** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs */
            $breadcrumbs = $resultPageFactory->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');
            $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('home', [
                'label' => __('Home'),
                'title' => __('Home'),
                'link' => $this->_url->getUrl('')
                    ]
            );
            $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('custom_module', [
                'label' => __('Test'),
                'title' => __('Test')
                    ]
            );
            return $resultPageFactory;
        }
    }
```

After Run

```
      bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

remove var/*

```
       rm -rf var/*
```

Now, check This is Works for me.

Comment: Got the Issue Need to use: \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory. Thanks it works fine :)