# Get Breadcrumb Path in Custom controller Magento 2

Tags: magento2, breadcrumbs

I am trying to get breadcrumb path in my controller by using this helper

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogData, ) {
$this->catalogData = $catalogData;
}
$path = $this->catalogData->getBreadcrumbPath();
```

When I print $path it's giving me an empty array. But when I get this helper function in any product phtml file like this

```
$helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data');
$values = $helper->getBreadcrumbPath();
```

it's giving me the full path in phtml. How can I access this function in my controller as well?

Comment: You can refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131878/magento-2-custom-module-frontend-error#answer-131885. May it help you